# Button "onclick" not working (being detected)

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, click

I have some code, but for some reason my `onclick="click()" is not being detected.

Here is the code:

```js
function click () {
  //Just for display purposes ON STACKOVERFLOW
  document.write("It worked!!!"); 
  name = document.getElementById("name").value; 
  document.getElementById("name").innerText = ""; 
  agenda.push(name); 
}
```

```css
.add {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 12px 0 10px 10px;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #e9ecef;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in-out;
  width: 700px; 
}

.add:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px) scale(1.02);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #d0ebff;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.add .submit {
  stroke: #adb5bd;
  transition: stroke 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.add:hover .submit {
  stroke: #495057;
  transition: stroke 0.1s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.submit {
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

input[type=text] {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="add" class="add">Add item: <input type="text" id="name" class="name" placeholder="Enter item name" autocomplete="off">
    <button id="submit" class="submit" onclick="click();">Add</button>
    </span>
```

I am receiving no error or anything, and I know that the function `click()` actually works, as I already tried calling it from the console, which also implies that the link between the JavaScript and HTML file(s) is working, as otherwise, the console wouldn't know what `click()` is.  Therefore, I know that the problem is with the actual HTML code.

Thanks.

Comment: rename to clickIt - click is reserved

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: 1. Do NOT use the name `click` for the function 2. Do NOT use the id or name `submit` for the button. 3. Do NOT use the id or name `name` for the field. 4. Do NOT use `document.write` after the page has rendered - instead use console.log

Comment: @epascarello That was because I didn't think that the console shows up on StackOverflow.

Comment: Also use better variable names: `var agenda = []

    document.getElementById("addBut").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("It worked!!!");
      var item = document.getElementById("item"), itemValue = item.value;
      item.select(); item.focus();
      agenda.push(itemValue);
      console.log(agenda)
    })`